# Flutter : SliverAppBar actions button

Tags: flutter

I put a `IconButton` to `SliverAppBar` actions , but the output compress to oval shape

[image]

```
actions: [
  IconButton(
    splashRadius: 23,
    icon: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFF05122B),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Center(child: Icon(OIcons.share, color: Colors.white, size: 20))
    ),
    onPressed: (){
      
    },
  ),
],
```

if using `shape` with `padding` , icon not align center

[image]

```
IconButton(
  splashRadius: 23,
  icon: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Color(0xFF05122B),
      shape: BoxShape.circle
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Center(child: Icon(OIcons.share, color: Colors.white, size: 20))
  ),
  onPressed: (){

  },
),
```

if using `shape` with `width` and `height` , no matter how much width and height is set, the button size still small.

[image]

```
IconButton(
  splashRadius: 23,
  icon: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Color(0xFF05122B),
      shape: BoxShape.circle
    ),
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    child: Center(child: Icon(OIcons.share, color: Colors.white, size: 20))
  ),
  onPressed: (){

  },
),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CircleAvatar` instead of `Container`

```
CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF05122B),
    child: IconButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        splashRadius: 23,
        icon: Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
        onPressed: () {},
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: nice. work as expected, and not losing the way i want to customization

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shape` instead of `borderRadius` on `BoxDecoration`. To increase the `icon` size, you need to use `iconSize:x`

```dart
IconButton(
  splashRadius: 24,
  iconSize: 43,
  icon: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Color(0xFF05122B),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

Comment: Hi, but if using shape, button cant sizing anymore, no matter is using width , height or padding

Comment: Can you an image that  you are trying to archive?

Comment: updated question. `shape` is not the answer I want. it will force to circle but lost the ability to customize the button

Comment: use `iconSize` for that.

Comment: Thank you. also one of the solution.